# How can I query in Bookshelf/Knex on a BelongsToMany join table?

Tags: mysql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am running Bookshelf over MySQL in a Node application.

I have a model called Document and another called Tag, which are joined through a belongsToMany relationship via a table called "map_tag_document".

Document:

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../bootstrap/bookshelf_instance').bookshelf;
const Tag = require('./tag').model;

const Document = bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'document',
        tags() {
            return this.belongsToMany(Tag, 'map_tag_document', 'document_id', 'tag_id')
        }
    },
    {
        jsonColumns: ['data']
    }
);

module.exports.model = Document;
```

Tag:

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../bootstrap/bookshelf_instance').bookshelf;

const Tag = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'tag'
});

module.exports.model = Tag;
```

Tags have a "name" column.

How do I query documents based on a search string appearing in the names of the tags associated with them?

Currently, I'm querying like this:

```
await new Document()
                .query((qb) => {
                    if (searchString)
                        qb.whereRaw(`(data->'$.description' LIKE "%${searchString}%" OR name LIKE "%${searchString}%")`)
                })
                .fetch({
                    withRelated: ['tags']
                });
```

What's the proper syntax for querying on the joined table?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out-can do joins on the Knex querybuilder object, like this:

```
        const documents = await new Document()
            .query((qb) => {
                qb.join('map_tag_document', 'document.id', '=', 'map_tag_document.document_id')
                qb.join('tag', 'tag.id', '=', 'map_tag_document.tag_id')
                if (searchString)
                    qb.andWhereRaw(`(document.data->'$.description' LIKE "%${searchString}%" OR document.name LIKE "%${searchString}%" OR tag.name LIKE "%${searchString}%")`)
            })
            .fetch({
                withRelated: ['tags']
            });
```